# python untar linux equivalent

Tags: python, linux, unix, tar

What would be the equivalent linux command to do the following:

```
>>> import tarfile
>>> filepath = "./backup.tar.gz"
>>> tar = tarfile.open(filepath, "r:gz")
>>> tar.extractall()
>>> tar.close()
```

I believe the answer is something along the lines of:

```
$ tar -xvzf ./backup.tar.gz .
```

But wanted to make sure the two things do the exact same thing.

Comment: Do you have a *specific problem* with `tar -xzf ./backup.tar.gz` leading to the question being asked? (The usual guidance that Stack Overflow questions should be based on specific issues holds here as much as anywhere).

Comment: (...also, as usual, questions about UNIX tool command-line usage are generally a better fit for our sister site [unix.se]).

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/tarfile.py#L2486

Comment: @felipsmartins oh perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tar` to do that.

```
tar -xvf ./backup.tar.gz

-x = extract
-f = file
-v = verbose
```

Edit:

On some implementations you may need to add the `-z` flag.
Here is the note from `tar`'s `man` page.

```
-z, --gunzip, --gzip
  (c mode only) Compress the resulting archive with gzip(1).  In extract or list modes, this option is ignored.  Note that, unlike other tar implementations, this implementation recognizes gzip compression automatically when reading archives.
```

Comment: `-v`? The OP's Python code doesn't print verbose output.

Comment: Just a habit for me with tar to always include `-v`

Comment: Also, you *do* need `-z` to support a `.gz` file as input.

Comment: That seems to be implementation dependant.       ```-z, --gunzip, --gzip
             (c mode only) Compress the resulting archive with gzip(1).  In extract or list modes, this option is ignored.  Note that, unlike other tar imple-
             mentations, this implementation recognizes gzip compression automatically when reading archives.```

Comment: *nod*. One of the tricky things about there not *being* a POSIX standard for `tar`; to get a guaranteed-identical-across-compliant-platforms answer, one would need to switch to the (POSIX-defined, albeit not as widely deployed) `pax` tool instead.